# JDBC helper that reduces boilerplate code

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource

I am using the `c3p0` library as my datasource object.

---

I want to create a JDBC helper class that helps reduce the boilerplate code that JDBC has and I am wondering if my implementation is correct and are following best practices? Also, if there is an already existing library that provides these functionalities, like `QueryRunner`, maybe?

---

Most of my queries returns a list of results of a specified column. Will it be okay if I use the following helper method for all my queries?

```
public List<String> retrieveSQLQuery(String sqlQuery, String column) {    
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery)) {

        while (rs.next()) {                    
            values.add(rs.getString(column));
        }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }    
      return values;
}
```

The `getConnection()` method lives in a `JDBCUtil` class which provides the connection to the datasource object. This helper class will be extending `JDBCUtil` thus why it has access to that method.

---

I also know that frameworks like spring and Hibernate provide utilities, however, those frameworks are too large for my project.

Comment: You can use spring-jdbc without dragging in the rest of spring. Eating the SQLException is a bad practice, spring-jdbc converts the SQLException into a DataAccessException specific to the error based on the status codes returned for the database you're using.

Comment: http://www.jooq.org/ sounds like a good fit for your use case.

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks for the suggesting, however, I prefer not to use spring because of the potential risk of having spring components that are not compatible with other frameworks.

Comment: Add a `finally` block and close rs, statement, and conn.  Also, not sure if the helper class should extend JDBCUtil - it sounds more like composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Rejecting Spring on the basis of might not be compatible with other frameworks is a bad move. Spring is normally the glue between your project and any other framework. If you want to write this code yourself for practice than it is fine, but anything even remotely serious you should not really take just a simplistic approach. The complexity of a DB management layer does not stop at a return value of `List<String>`.

Comment: @GergelyBacso Totally agree. K i will try and move towards spring jdbc. However, I will still like to know if my approach is correct or not.

Comment: @AndrewS It is using try-with-resources so it doesn't need the finally block because it closed automatically.

Comment: We can tell whether your approach was good or not if you tell us what the goal was. As we agreed, for any sensibe use case you will be better off using some library. If it was for practicing, then yes, it works so it is good.